# Does this small probate estate require probate?

Tags: united-states, new-jersey, trusts-and-estates

A person dies with a probate estate of about $9,000 and 8 million dollars inside a living revocable trust. I would not call this a small estate but I would call it a small probate estate.

In this case, can the executor of the estate skip probate?

Comment: See this answer https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/93161/does-this-require-probate The non-probate assets are not counted.